# deciding team lead and assigning users to team in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to assign a team lead and members(users) to team. I have created "has many and through" association between teams and users tables as one team may have many users and a user can be assigned to many teams. For getting team lead for every team, I have put team_lead column in teams table.

Doubts: 1. Is this right way to put team_lead column in teams table to assign team lead to a team , when team is being created.

2. When a team is created, It will have a team lead and some users which are already existed in db. How to assign users to team ?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams, through: :user_teams
    has_many :user_teams
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :is_admin, :contact_no, :birth_date, :joining_date, :is_active, :is_hr, :is_manager
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :user_teams
  has_many :users, through: :user_teams
end
```

team_user.rb

```
class TeamsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :team_id, :team_lead, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

At the time of team creation, I want to assign a team lead and users to a team. How to implement this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more easily model a many-to-many relationshop between users and teams using `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Then your models would look like this:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams

  ...
end

class Team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_one :team_lead, class_name: "User"

  ...
end
```

Note that `Team` also has a `team_lead`, which is also of type `User`.

Then it's easy to create a new team with team lead:

```
team = Team.new
team.team_lead = existing_user1
team.users << existing_user2
team.save
```

To make the many-to-many relationship work you'll also need a join table called `teams_users`. See the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more information on setting up the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: hi fivedigit, thanks for your reply. Do I need to create team_lead table or existing user table is enough to get team lead and user.I already have team_users table.

Comment: Team leads are in the `users` table. Note that you'll need a join table called `teams_users` (plural names). Please read the linked section of the Rails Docs which say exactly how to do this.